# Opencv Camshift with threading not working

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to run the opencv/samples/python2 provided code for Camshift using threads.I've created two objects for App() class which call the run method.

```
    ##
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
import cv2
import video


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, video_src):
         self.cam = video.create_capture(video_src)
         ret, self.frame = self.cam.read()
         cv2.namedWindow('camshift')
         cv2.setMouseCallback('camshift', self.onmouse)

          self.selection = None
          self.drag_start = None
          self.tracking_state = 0
          self.show_backproj = False

   def onmouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
         x, y = np.int16([x, y]) # BUG
         if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
              self.drag_start = (x, y)
              self.tracking_state = 0
         if self.drag_start:
              if flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
                   h, w = self.frame.shape[:2]
                   xo, yo = self.drag_start
                   x0, y0 = np.maximum(0, np.minimum([xo, yo], [x, y]))
                   x1, y1 = np.minimum([w, h], np.maximum([xo, yo], [x, y]))
                   self.selection = None
                   if x1-x0 > 0 and y1-y0 > 0:
                        self.selection = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
             else:
                   self.drag_start = None
                  if self.selection is not None:
                         self.tracking_state = 1

    def show_hist(self):
        bin_count = self.hist.shape[0]
        bin_w = 24
        img = np.zeros((256, bin_count*bin_w, 3), np.uint8)
        for i in xrange(bin_count):
             h = int(self.hist[i])
             cv2.rectangle(img, (i*bin_w+2, 255), ((i+1)*bin_w-2, 255-h),                 (int(180.0*i/bin_count), 255, 255), -1)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        cv2.imshow('hist', img)

   def run(self):
     while True:
        ret, self.frame = self.cam.read()
        vis = self.frame.copy()
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array((0., 60., 32.)), np.array((180., 255., 255.)))

        if self.selection:
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.selection
            self.track_window = (x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0)
            hsv_roi = hsv[y0:y1, x0:x1]
            mask_roi = mask[y0:y1, x0:x1]
            hist = cv2.calcHist( [hsv_roi], [0], mask_roi, [16], [0, 180] )
            cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
            self.hist = hist.reshape(-1)
            #self.show_hist()
            vis_roi = vis[y0:y1, x0:x1]

            cv2.bitwise_not(vis_roi, vis_roi)
            vis[mask == 0] = 0

        if self.tracking_state == 1:
            self.selection = None
            prob = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], self.hist, [0, 180], 1)
            prob &= mask
            term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )
            track_box, self.track_window = cv2.CamShift(prob, self.track_window, term_crit)
            print track_box[0]
            if self.show_backproj:
                vis[:] = prob[...,np.newaxis]
            try: cv2.ellipse(vis, track_box, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            except: print track_box

        cv2.imshow('camshift', vis)

        ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break
        if ch == ord('b'):
            self.show_backproj = not self.show_backproj
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     import sys
     try: video_src = sys.argv[1]
     except: video_src = 0
     print __doc__
     left=App(1)# 1=device id for left camera
     right=App(2)#2=device id for right camera
     threadLeft=Process(target=left.run())
     threadRight=Process(target=right.run())
     threadRight.start()
     threadLeft.start()
```

On execution , two windows appear one for right and other for left.However the onmouse() is not being called when i'm dragging the mouse on either of the windows.Seems that the windows freeze.Following which, on closing either one of them , the pattern which i made previously on the window to track any object , gets used in the second unclosed window automatically.

So is there any other method with which i can call this code for my two camera's .Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: try adding `threadLeft.join(); threadRight.join()` to the end of the code.  This explicitly waits for the processes to finish, instead of running off the end.

Comment: even though i do thread.join() method  , it will just reunite the thread with my main ui thread at termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Process, give a function to `target`.  In the above code, `left.run()` is *executed*, not passed to Process.

Change the code to this:

```
threadLeft = Process(target=left.run)
threadRight = Process(target=right.run)
```

Comment: I think some deadlock condition is occurring

Comment: would you put the updated in Pastebin or something? Now I'm curious to run the code and see what's going on.  What packages need to be installed?

Comment: sure..install opencv , numpy and with opencv you will find a video.pyc file included in its samples folder..so use that also..Thanks though

Comment: I tried with adding many print commands in between , but it seems to stop working after it enters into the while loop.before if self.selection: statement...which i think will mean that the mouse listner is failing or creating the deadlock

Comment: @user3588406 I got the single camera case to work. If you select a region, a vibrating red ellipse appears. You can grab it with your hand and squeeze it! Have fun. http://pastebin.com/xz1sED4E

Comment: thanks..though..!!! even i just managed to solve it..
Got both to work!!!.. Problem was the the thread didnt get destroyed..Like everytime the main thread has to end completely..So i added a termination criteria and it worked.!! Once again thanks a lot..

Btw did u start the one camera by
a=App(camera_id).run()..

??

Comment: I started with `App(0)` and a thread.  You're welcome!  If you would, please mark this answer as "accepted" Thanks

Comment: Process part was right in the thread..on ur part..
Rest of the debugging was due to the fact that there was problem in thread destruction.I've used the same code which i posted in pastebin , and made a thread termination sequence.now it works perfect..